# Different ways to insert join table of Many-to-many relationships have different results in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I defined data models `User`, `Group` and `Membership` such that a user can join a group via `Membership`.

```java
// User.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME_", length = 20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD_", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Membership> memberships = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Set<Membership> getMemberships() {
        return memberships;
    }

    public void setMemberships(Set<Membership> memberships) {
        this.memberships = memberships;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

```java
// Group.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP_")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_")
    private final String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Membership> memberships = new HashSet<>();

    public Group(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Membership> getMemberships() {
        return memberships;
    }

    public void setMemberships(Set<Membership> memberships) {
        this.memberships = memberships;
    }
}
```

```java
// Membership.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBERSHIP_")
public class Membership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_")
    private User member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_")
    private Group group;

    @Column(name = "JOINED_TIME_")
    private LocalDateTime joinedTime;

    public Membership(LocalDateTime joinDateTime) {
        this.joinedTime = joinDateTime;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public User getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getJoinedTime() {
        return joinedTime;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void setMember(User member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public void setJoinedTime(LocalDateTime joinedTime) {
        this.joinedTime = joinedTime;
    }
}
```

Now I want to insert a membership relation to database, so I wrote the following test cases. In the first test case I persisted `Membership` that has both `User` and `Group`. In the second case I added membership to user and persisted user. In the last case I added membership to group and persisted the group. It turned out only the second case actually inserted the membership.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;
    
    // Persist relationship
    // Failed
    @Test
    public void should_add_membership_from_membership() {
        var user = new User("user1", "password");
        var group = new Group("group1");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.persist(group);
        var membership = new Membership(LocalDateTime.now());
        membership.setMember(user);
        membership.setGroup(group);
        //user.getMemberships().add(membership);
        entityManager.persist(membership);

        var dbUser = repository.findById("user1");
        assertTrue(dbUser.isPresent());
        assertEquals(1, dbUser.get().getMemberships().size());
        // user.setMemberships(new Membership(123, ));
    }
    
    // Persist user with added membership
    
    @Test
    // Passed
    public void should_add_membership_from_user() {
        var user = new User("user1", "password");
        var group = new Group("group1");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.persist(group);
        var membership = new Membership(LocalDateTime.now());
        membership.setGroup(group);
        user.getMemberships().add(membership); // Add from user side
        entityManager.persist(user);

        var dbUser = repository.findById("user1");
        assertTrue(dbUser.isPresent());
        assertEquals(1, dbUser.get().getMemberships().size());
        // user.setMemberships(new Membership(123, ));
    }
   
    // Persist group with added membership
    @Test
    // Failed
    public void should_add_membership_from_group() {
        var user = new User("user1", "password");
        var group = new Group("group1");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.persist(group);
        var membership = new Membership(LocalDateTime.now());
        membership.setGroup(group);
        group.getMemberships().add(membership); // Add from group side
        entityManager.persist(user);

        var dbUser = repository.findById("user1");
        assertTrue(dbUser.isPresent());
        assertEquals(1, dbUser.get().getMemberships().size());
    }
}
```

Here are logs in all test cases

- First

```
18:43:20.425 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: using SpringBootContextLoader
18:43:20.433 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -- Could not detect default resource locations for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:43:20.434 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: UserRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:43:20.513 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using ContextCustomizers for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, ImportsContextCustomizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer]
18:43:20.634 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider -- Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat\build\classes\java\main\haohanyang\springchat\server\SpringChatServerApplication.class]
18:43:20.636 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration haohanyang.springchat.server.SpringChatServerApplication for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest
18:43:20.689 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, ReactorContextTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
18:43:20.692 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener -- Before test class: class [UserRepositoryTest], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
18:43:20.714 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener -- Performing dependency injection for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-04-19T18:43:21.296+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Starting UserRepositoryTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 32264 (started by haohan in C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat)
2023-04-19T18:43:21.298+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-19T18:43:21.853+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-19T18:43:21.950+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-19T18:43:22.388+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-19T18:43:22.740+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:e5afb49d-6155-4e4f-825f-c87803336629 user=SA
2023-04-19T18:43:22.743+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-19T18:43:22.816+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-19T18:43:22.931+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-19T18:43:23.587+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-04-19T18:43:24.788+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Group (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2023-04-19T18:43:24.833+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Membership (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Hibernate: drop table if exists group_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists membership_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists membership__seq
Hibernate: create sequence membership__seq start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create table group_ (id_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (id_))
Hibernate: create table membership_ (id bigint not null, joined_time_ timestamp(6), group_ varchar(255), member_ varchar(20), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table user_ (username_ varchar(20) not null, password_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (username_))
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FK1udya4gvkv075w9wno3743i39 foreign key (group_) references group_
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FKthdd3se5969gd80afjg8yml8i foreign key (member_) references user_
2023-04-19T18:43:25.133+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-19T18:43:25.153+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-19T18:43:25.593+02:00  INFO 32264 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Started UserRepositoryTest in 4.814 seconds (process running for 6.482)
Hibernate: select next value for membership__seq

expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

- Second

```
18:44:31.394 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: using SpringBootContextLoader
18:44:31.401 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -- Could not detect default resource locations for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:44:31.402 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: UserRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:44:31.474 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using ContextCustomizers for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, ImportsContextCustomizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer]
18:44:31.569 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider -- Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat\build\classes\java\main\haohanyang\springchat\server\SpringChatServerApplication.class]
18:44:31.570 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration haohanyang.springchat.server.SpringChatServerApplication for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest
18:44:31.624 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, ReactorContextTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
18:44:31.626 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener -- Before test class: class [UserRepositoryTest], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
18:44:31.646 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener -- Performing dependency injection for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-04-19T18:44:32.223+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Starting UserRepositoryTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 18164 (started by haohan in C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat)
2023-04-19T18:44:32.226+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-19T18:44:32.751+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-19T18:44:32.847+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-19T18:44:33.301+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-19T18:44:33.645+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:0f8724d0-fc30-4034-bec6-69e75f6c5a17 user=SA
2023-04-19T18:44:33.648+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-19T18:44:33.714+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-19T18:44:33.829+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-19T18:44:34.470+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-04-19T18:44:35.666+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Group (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2023-04-19T18:44:35.712+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Membership (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Hibernate: drop table if exists group_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists membership_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists membership__seq
Hibernate: create sequence membership__seq start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create table group_ (id_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (id_))
Hibernate: create table membership_ (id bigint not null, joined_time_ timestamp(6), group_ varchar(255), member_ varchar(20), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table user_ (username_ varchar(20) not null, password_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (username_))
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FK1udya4gvkv075w9wno3743i39 foreign key (group_) references group_
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FKthdd3se5969gd80afjg8yml8i foreign key (member_) references user_
2023-04-19T18:44:36.000+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-19T18:44:36.019+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-19T18:44:36.445+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Started UserRepositoryTest in 4.735 seconds (process running for 6.252)
2023-04-19T18:44:36.823+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-19T18:44:36.823+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: drop table if exists group_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists membership_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists membership__seq
2023-04-19T18:44:36.828+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-19T18:44:36.829+02:00  INFO 18164 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
18:44:36: Execution finished ':test --tests "haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest.should_add_membership_from_user"'.
```

- Third

```
18:45:20.673 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: using SpringBootContextLoader
18:45:20.682 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -- Could not detect default resource locations for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:45:20.683 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest]: UserRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:45:20.755 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using ContextCustomizers for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, ImportsContextCustomizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer]
18:45:20.848 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider -- Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat\build\classes\java\main\haohanyang\springchat\server\SpringChatServerApplication.class]
18:45:20.849 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration haohanyang.springchat.server.SpringChatServerApplication for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest
18:45:20.896 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper -- Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [UserRepositoryTest]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, ReactorContextTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
18:45:20.898 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener -- Before test class: class [UserRepositoryTest], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
18:45:20.917 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener -- Performing dependency injection for test class haohanyang.springchat.server.repositories.UserRepositoryTest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-04-19T18:45:21.504+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Starting UserRepositoryTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 17312 (started by haohan in C:\Users\haohan\Projects\springchat)
2023-04-19T18:45:21.506+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-19T18:45:22.053+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-19T18:45:22.160+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-19T18:45:22.614+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-19T18:45:22.955+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:80be883e-488c-46b7-8108-3be59e84964d user=SA
2023-04-19T18:45:22.958+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-19T18:45:23.027+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-19T18:45:23.144+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-19T18:45:23.775+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-04-19T18:45:24.967+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Group (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2023-04-19T18:45:25.014+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: haohanyang.springchat.server.models.Membership (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Hibernate: drop table if exists group_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists membership_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists membership__seq
Hibernate: create sequence membership__seq start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create table group_ (id_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (id_))
Hibernate: create table membership_ (id bigint not null, joined_time_ timestamp(6), group_ varchar(255), member_ varchar(20), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table user_ (username_ varchar(20) not null, password_ varchar(255) not null, primary key (username_))
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FK1udya4gvkv075w9wno3743i39 foreign key (group_) references group_
Hibernate: alter table if exists membership_ add constraint FKthdd3se5969gd80afjg8yml8i foreign key (member_) references user_
2023-04-19T18:45:25.328+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-19T18:45:25.349+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-19T18:45:25.785+02:00  INFO 17312 --- [    Test worker] h.s.s.repositories.UserRepositoryTest    : Started UserRepositoryTest in 4.804 seconds (process running for 6.329)

expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

I would appreciate it a lot for identifying the reason and suggest the best practice in this scenarios.

Comment: your test scenarios do not even try to save ("flush") data into DB. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your second case also did not work as you expect because data is not coming from the database, it shows true because you manually add `user.getMemberships().add(membership); // Add from user side` by this line when you get this object by id again, it is present because you get the same object, for your confirmation you can add a debugger at findById line and see data is not saved in a database or you can print the address of the object it must be the same.

And you can also enable MySQL query by this line `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`. and do not forget to flush data before call findById.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide the solution in step-wise order and avoid using very long sentences for instructions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).